# TypeScript module, only referenced by type, is still a runtime-dependency

Tags: typescript

I want to do something similar as described in ["Optional Module Loading and Other Advanced Loading Scenarios"](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios), but it's not working.

Consider these two files:

**module1.ts**:

```
// declare function require(moduleNames: string[], onLoad: (...args: any[]) => void): void;
/// <reference path="./require.d.ts"/>

import { Module2 as M2 } from "./module2";

var needsLazyLoading:boolean = false;

if (needsLazyLoading) {
    require(["./module2"], (Module2: typeof M2) => {
        let module2 = new Module2();
        if (module2.someMethod("...")) { /* ... */ }
    });
}
```

**module2.ts**:

```
export class Module2 {
  public someMethod(s:string):boolean{ return true; } /* ... */
 }
```

Now, I compile `module1.ts` like this:

```
tsc --module amd --outFile moduleFull1.js module1.ts
```

According to the article I cited above, I would not expect `moduleFull1.js` to have any reference to `Module2` (the same is suggested in ["Use case: Lazy loading"](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html)).

However, it's there...

**moduleFull1.js**:

```
define("module2", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var Module2 = (function () {
        function Module2() {
        }
        return Module2;
    }());
    exports.Module2 = Module2;
});
define("module1", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
});
```

(which defeats the purpose of lazy-loading).

Why is this? Am I missing something?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that a "declaration space" has properties that it does not have. There are many declaration spaces (see TypeScript Language Spec 1.8 [Section 2.3 Declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#23-declarations) for more information) and they're there to ensure that identifiers are resolved appropriately.

Let's take a look at the links you cited.

In the link for Lazy Loading, I note only that it deals with an explicit `require('foo')` syntax and that the location it appears will affect when the requirement, and subsequent load, take place.

In the link for Optional Module Loading, I note it says the following.

> If a module identifier is **only ever used as part of a type annotations**
>   **and never as an expression**, then no require call is emitted for that
>   module.

Your code is clearly not using Module2 as a type annotation, so it's going to be required.

Comment: How could I fix my code and use "Module2 as a type annotation"?

Comment: If I change my code to mimmic the example given in the handbook, the problem remains: Module2 is present in the final file.